# React Native - ExpoPixi : Illegal invocation

Tags: react-native, expo

im new to use RactNative.
so i want to build web app using RN and use `ExpoPixi` to build `signature`.

When i try to import the `ExpoPixi`, it return error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Illegal invocation` on Chrome.

this is my component

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ExpoPixi from 'expo-pixi';

export const Registration: React.FC<Props> = (props, { text }) => {
  let signRef = useRef(null);
  return(
   <ExpoPixi.Signature
     ref={signRef}
     strokeWidth={3}
     strokeAlpha={0.5}
   />
 )
}
```

is that error related to `webpack`?
what should i do?

Comment: Is ExpoPixi using TypeScript files ? This type of files are not supported in web

Comment: actually i dont know but i used TypeScript in my project. Oh? So ExpoPixi isnt supported on web?